# How to generate pdf using NSData or using data bytes objective c?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

Hi I want to write pdf using `NSData` or using data bytes given by webservice ?

```
    -(NSData *)saveData:(NSData*)fileData fileName:(NSString *)fileName fileType:(NSString *)fileType
{
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory , NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.%@",documentsDir,fileName,fileType];

    NSData* downloadData = [NSData dataWithData:fileData];

    [fileManager createFileAtPath:filePath contents:downloadData attributes:nil];


}
```

I am using this but it's not working it's give me error "It may be damaged or use a file format that Preview doesn’t recognize." on opening that pdf created by above code.

Comment: It's a much better idea to just use `NSData`'s `writeToFile:atomically:` than going through NSFileManager.

Comment: Is the data already in the PDF format or are you looking for a way to convert some other data to PDF? Can you try to inspect your file using a Hex Editor ([Hex Fiend](http://ridiculousfish.com/hexfiend/) is awesome). Most likely you’ll figure out what format the data is in.

Comment: You can also use the `file` command-line tool to figure out the real type of some file.

Comment: @RaphaelSchweikert - Yes it's in pdf format..

Comment: And you know that how…? Does it open in any other PDF viewer besides Preview?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can convert `NSData` to `PDF` with bellow code... I get the bellow Code From [This link](http://pastebin.com/kpjsX6xH)

```
NSString *string=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.pdf",[yourArray objectAtIndex:pageIndex]];
[controller1 addAttachmentData:pdfData mimeType:@"application/pdf" fileName:string];
[self presentModalViewController:controller1 animated:YES];
[controller1 release];

//to convert pdf to NSData
NSString *pdfPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.pdf"];
NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:pdfPath];

//to convert NSData to pdf
NSData *data               = //some nsdata
CFDataRef myPDFData        = (CFDataRef)data;
CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData(myPDFData);
CGPDFDocumentRef pdf       = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithProvider(provider);

-(IBAction)saveasPDF:(id)sender{
     NSString *string=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.pdf",[yourArray objectAtIndex:pageIndex]];
     [controller1 addAttachmentData:pdfData mimeType:@"application/pdf" fileName:string];
     [self presentModalViewController:controller1 animated:YES];
     [pdfData writeToFile:[self getDBPathPDf:string] atomically:YES];
}

-(NSString *) getDBPathPDf:(NSString *)PdfName {
       NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory , NSUserDomainMask, YES);
       NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        return [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:PdfName];
}
```

---

**Summary**:
get NSData from pdf file path

```
NSData *pdfData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:pathToFile1];
NSLog(@"pdfData= %d", pdfData != nil);
```

write NSData to pdf file

```
[pdfData writeToFile:pathToFile2 atomically:YES];
```

Comment: @ParasJoshi, I tried to save the file using "writeToFile:" but it doesn't open the file in Preview.app. Any help how to save the above CGPDFDocumentRef object to pdf file

Comment: Does anyone have this for Swift 2?

Answer (score 3):

@ChallengerGuy  (If you are still looking for the Swift 2 approach for the CGPDFDocument)

```
//to convert data of type NSData 

    guard let cfData = CFDataCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, UnsafePointer<UInt8>(data.bytes), data.length) else { return nil}

    let cgDataProvider =  CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData(cfData)

    guard let cgPDFDocument  =  CGPDFDocumentCreateWithProvider(cgDataProvider) else { return nil }
```

Hope the above helps