# Convert byte array to PDF in swift 3

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swift3

What am trying to do is, get the byte array response from api response, and save that to file (PDF).

(Server returns a bytearray)

Am using `Alamofire` for web requests,

```
Alamofire.request("\(BaseUrl)api/mobile/downloadResume", headers : ProfileViewHeader)
        .response { response in
    print(response)
        // let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
        // let filePath = "\(documentsPath)/readingfile.pdf"
        // let data:NSData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: response.data) as NSData
        // let file = data.write(toFile: filePath, atomically: false)
}
```

Am getting the byte array response without any issues,

My main problem is how to save the byte array in a file. I have done the same in Android without any issues, but not able achieve the same in swift,

Any kind of help will be greatly appreciated. Please help me out.

Thanks

Comment: you can take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16806739/how-to-generate-pdf-using-nsdata-or-using-data-bytes-objective-c)

Comment: @ovo Thanks for your support, but is it related to swift?

Comment: Remove the `NSKeyedArchiver` part. Just directly call `response.data.write(...)`.

Comment: To open the PDF in a web view, you need only to get `URL` to that file, `URLRequest` from that and load it.

Comment: @Sulthan Thanks for your support, i know to open the file in web view, no issues with that,but its the saving part.

Comment: @Sulthan Would you mind explaining me about the suggestion you have made about the `NSKeyedArchiver` part?

Comment: `NSKeyedArchiver` is used to encode/decode objects (conforming to `Coding` protocol) into `Data` on the device (similar to serialization in Java). It's not used to decode data sent from the server. The server already sends you raw PDF data, you don't have to do anything with them, just save them to a file.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it and will let you know.

Answer (score 2):

For future readers, this is what worked for me using swiftyJson:

```
let documentDirectory = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)

let fileURL = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent("TEST2.pdf")

let bytes = json["Recibo"].arrayObject as! [UInt8]

let data = Data(bytes);
data.write(to: fileURL, options: .atomic)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Alamofire, the result is inside data. You could do so to save in a file under document directory.

```
   override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {


    Alamofire.request("LINK", headers : nil)
    .response { response in
        print(response.data ?? "")


        self.createPDF(pdfData: response.data!)
    }
}


func createPDF( pdfData : Data) {
    let render = UIPrintPageRenderer()

    let html = "<b>Hello <i>World!</i></b> <p>Generate PDF file from HTML in Swift</p>"
    let fmt = UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter(markupText: html)

    render.addPrintFormatter(fmt, startingAtPageAt: 0)

    // 3. Assign paperRect and printableRect

    let page = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 595.2, height: 841.8) // A4, 72 dpi
    let printable = page.insetBy(dx: 0, dy: 0)

    render.setValue(NSValue(cgRect: page), forKey: "paperRect")
    render.setValue(NSValue(cgRect: printable), forKey: "printableRect")

    // 4. Create PDF context and draw
    //let pointzero = CGPoint(x: 0,y :0)
    let rect = CGRect.zero


    let data = NSMutableData(base64Encoded: pdfData.base64EncodedData(), options: NSData.Base64DecodingOptions.ignoreUnknownCharacters);

    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(data!, rect, nil)


    for i in 1...render.numberOfPages {

        UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
        let bounds = UIGraphicsGetPDFContextBounds()
        render.drawPage(at: i - 1, in: bounds)
    }

    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();

    let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]

    // 5. Save PDF file
    do {
        let fileURL = try documentsPath.asURL().appendingPathComponent("file.pdf")
       try pdfData.write(to: fileURL, options: .atomic)

    } catch {

    }


    print("saved success")
}
```

createPDF function will get your byte array and generate a new pdf file based on that. 
An other way which is generic is just to save it like it is from the server

```
         let documentDirectory = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)

        // Save to a file
        let fileURL = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent("file.pdf")


        do {
            try  response.data?.base64EncodedData().write(to: fileURL, options: .atomic)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your support, Any further explanations for this answer?

Comment: Thanks, i will try this and will let you know :)

Comment: you could check [ifunbbox] (http://www.i-funbox.com/) for displaying the generated files under document directory.

Comment: @FaresBenHamouda how to view pdf in app?

Comment: [Pdf reader](https://github.com/Alua-Kinzhebayeva/iOS-PDF-Reader). 
That could help

Comment: @FaresBenHamouda Thanks